# Calculate score of statements based on frequencies of there words - java

Tags: java

In the following function i get

1- Hashap contains words and frequency of each of them .

2- and a map contains statements and array of words for each .

i try here to calculate total score of each statement based on sum of its words' frequencies but there is a problem in the counter ...

```
public HashMap get_words (HashMap m , Map ma)
    {
        HashMap<String , Integer > new_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int sent_sum , bfr ;
            Iterator it = ma.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
               // System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                //int len = ((String[]) pair.getValue()).length ;
                String[] s = (String[]) pair.getValue() ;
               // int[] sent_score ;
                bfr = 0 ;
                sent_sum = 0 ;

                    Iterator its = m.entrySet().iterator();

                    while ( its.hasNext() )
                    {
                        HashMap.Entry pair2 = (HashMap.Entry)its.next();

                        for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i ++ )
                        {
                            if ( pair2.getKey().toString() == s[i] )
                            {
                                bfr ++ ;
                                break ;
                            }
                        }
                        if ( bfr > 0 )
                            sent_sum += (Integer) pair2.getValue() ;
                      //  System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                        its.remove();

                    }
                    new_map.put( pair.getKey().toString() , sent_sum);

                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }

        return new_map ;
    }
```

//Thanks

Comment: `" but there is a problem in the counter ..."` --- and that problem is??

Comment: .... and it seems that we'll never know...

Comment: counter always equals zero

Comment: ..... and it seems that we'll not find an answer

Comment: Take your pick of answers: [word frequency using HashMap](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+hashmap+word+frequency+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).